# Using collation in oracle with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I would like to set a global configuration to COLLATION in ORACLE. When I'm setting the follow, simply, doesn't work (is not supported apparently):

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.UseCollation("BINARY");
}
```

But, when I use Linq syntax it works! (**EF.Functions.Collate(...)**)

```cs
   var result= await _context.Model
                     .Where(...)
                     .Select(s => new {...})
                     .OrderBy(o => EF.Functions.Collate(o.BlockAcronym, "BINARY"))
                     .ToListAsync();
```

How can I configure a global setting for collation? (not for each model/query)

Regards,
Gustavo